# jQuery comma-separated selectors vs variables for event driven function call

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, refactoring

Sorry for the long question. I have something like the following code:

```
$("#el1, #el2, #el3, #el4, #el5").on("spinstop", function (event, ui) { 
    updtpg() 
});
```

`#el1`, `#el2` etc. are all [jQuery UI spinners](http://api.jqueryui.com/spinner/). There are, however, several more than five on the page (around twenty, but some are sometimes hidden) among other buttons, dropdowns, and checkboxes. I hook up each one to the function `updtpg`, which grabs the values from the spinners and does some calculations, updating a results div.

I'm storing jQuery objects for each spinner in a global object like so:

```
var window.gQ = {};
gQ.$el1 = $("#el1");
gQ.$el2 = $("#el2");
```

... and using these in the `updtpg` function to grab the values of the spinners. What I'd like to do is *also* use properties in this global gQ object to hold the values of these spinners. That means, however, hooking up each spinner like so:

```
gQ.$el1.on("spinstop", function (event, ui) { 
    gQ.$val1 = gQ.$el1.val(); 
    updtpg(); 
});

gQ.$el2.on("spinstop", function (event, ui) { 
    gQ.$val2 = gQ.$el2.val(); 
    updtpg(); 
});
```

...and so on for every spinner. I don't mind doing that if it makes sense. And I guess that's my question. Is that the "correct" way. I think so because I don't want to have to read the val() function for each spinner every time one of them changes, but it also adds a *lot* of code. Pretty repetitive code, to boot. If there's a better way, and I can't imagine there's not, what is it?

And feel free to correct anything else you see that looks... uh, improvable. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Would it be possible to create a demo http://jsfiddle.net/? From what I understand now, you want to use some `class` on spinners, select them like this if they are dynamic `$('body').on('spinstop', '.spinner', function(event, ui) { // code goes here });`, also you can write values into elements using `$(this).data('spinValue', somevalue);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The rule of thumb is any time you replicate code there is a better way, below is an example. First create your main array, create your event handler for all the spinners. On each event we will create or update the array with the new value and call your function this will create a key value pair based on the spinner id.

```
// Create the main array
var gQ = {};

$( "#spinner1, #spinner2, #spinner3" ).on("spinstop",function (event, ui) {
    gQ[$(this).attr("id")] = $(this).val();
    updtpg(); 
});
```

Another tip is to use a class on each spinner so you dont have to specify all the ids but instead just one one class.

```
  <input id="spinner1" class="specialspinner" name="spinner" value="5.06" />
  <input id="spinner2" class="specialspinner" name="spinner" value="5.06" />
  <input id="spinner3" class="specialspinner" name="spinner" value="5.06" />

    $( ".specialspinner" ).on("spinstop",function (event, ui) {
        gQ[$(this).attr("id")] = $(this).val();
        updtpg(); 
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

HTML

```
<input class="spinner" id="spinnerOne" type="text" />
<input class="spinner" id="spinnerTwo" type="text" />
<input class="spinner" id="spinnerTree" type="text" />
<div id="values"></div>
```

JS (exchange the "change" event binding with binding to your "spinstop" event)

```
// values of spinner
var spinnerValues = {};

$('.spinner').each(function() {

    // save jquery object
    var $this = $(this);

    // get id of spinner for saving values reference
    var spinnerId = $this.attr('id');

    // init values object
    spinnerValues[spinnerId] = $this.val();

    // attach event callback
    $this.on('change', function (event, ui) {

        // update values
        spinnerValues[spinnerId] = $this.val();

        // debug output - remove later!
        console.log(spinnerValues);

    });

});
```

JSFiddle Example: http://jsfiddle.net/QNwjd/